# By using the fact that $\log(n)<<n$，evaluate $\lim n^{1/n}$.

Tags: calculus

By using the fact that $\log(n)<<n$，evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n}$$

How to use $\log(n)<<n$ to evaluate that?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: What have you already tried? If you can add your workings and thoughts to the question you'll get more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\large {(\log n)^\frac1n = e^{\frac{\log n}n}}$$

Comment: thank you,i got it.

Comment: @miny Well done! You are welcome. That's a standard trick for the manipulation of expressions like $f(x)^{g(x)}$ in calculus with $f(x)>0$. Keep that in mind! Bye